# I want to print the value of "i" in pine script

Tags: pine-script

I want to print the value of "i" once the condition is true.
for example:
close > ema(close,1), close > ema(close,2) and close > ema(close,3)

I want to print 1,2 and 3

this is the code

```
//@version=4
study("My Script")

ma(x) =>
    ema = x
    for i = 1 to 20
        ema := ema(x,i)
        tick = x > ema ? i : 0


plot(ma(close))
```

Answer (score 2):

There's a bug with build-in methods and an index of a loop used as a length, so you should use pine implementation of `ema`:

```
//@version=4
study("My Script")

pine_ema(x, y) =>
    alpha = 2 / (y + 1)
    sum = 0.0
    sum := alpha * x + (1 - alpha) * nz(sum[1])

ma(src) =>
    retVal = 0
    for i = 1 to 20
        ema = pine_ema(src,i)
        if src > ema
            retVal := retVal + 1
    retVal

plot(ma(close))
```

Comment: Thank you, but it didn't give me more than 2. I want to know how many times close is greater than ema. and thank you again

Comment: So you want to count amount of times out those 20 when `close > ema()`?

Comment: exactly! that's what I want.

Comment: I've changed the implementation.

Comment: thank you so much for your kindness help, but the result comes 0 or 20 I just want to ask how I can add sum inside it, so if src is above of i so it will be counted as +i and if not it will be -i. for example src is above ema (1,2,3) and below ema (4,5 ... 20) so the count will be  (1+2+3-4-5-...-20)

Comment: Use `i` instead of `1` in the code ¯\_(ツ)_/¯ Might I ask you, do you have any clue how to program?

Comment: I already tested it but still get 2 values only, I am still a beginner :(

Comment: I think I got what's your problem. EMA depends on the previous value of the calculation and when you call the same function from the same place, the function is taken the value from the previous calculation for ema[1], which is not correct in your case. So the only possible way I see is use 20 ema with different parameters. So without the loop.